# Fire event after user is authenticated - windows authentication c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, windows-authentication

I have used windows authentication in my application. I want to add log for successful login but can not find any event which fired after login only once.

I tried to add code in global.asax Application_AuthenticateRequest event but this event fires every time. Also tried to add logic in base controller but same thing happens.

So please help me to find the event where i can add logic for insert logs for success login into database,

Answer (score 0):

Best will be to add a log from the stored procedure that executes to authenticate. If it is successful, add log of success, either of failure. You won't need to look for events.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But i used windows authentication so there is no store procedure for authentication. so need any server side event where i can add logic for insert logs.

Comment: You will land in a code block after the successful completion of windows authentication - add logs from there?